# how to you log a user out with a get request by deleting the jwt token

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I am trying to logout a user by using a get request.

but while sending the request in postman it comes back with a error message of user not defined. But since it is a get request how do you specify the current user?
My idea was just to set the tokens lifetime to 1 milliseconds.

```
const logout = async (req, res) => {
//logout the user by setting the token to 1 milliseconds
   try {  
      const { JWT_SECRET, JWT_LIFETIME } = process.env;
      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name,
        },
        JWT_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: 1 }
      );
      return res.status(200).json({
        msg: "User successfully logged out",
        token: token,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        msg: err.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

The route is `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/logout`

Answer (score -1):

```
const logout = async (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('token', '', {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000),
  })
  return res
    .status(200)
    .json({ success: true, msg: 'User successfully logged out' })
}
```

So the explanation of this is that you reset the JWT token to null and then set a new expire time from the current time for one miller second from then. This will mean that the authentication for the token "User" will restrict the user from doing anything effectively logging them out.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: awesome! added the explanation thanks for the tip.

Comment: Not a complete logout, unfortunately.  The correct way is to add the user's JWT to a list of invalidated tokens.  The token may have been copied over and may be used to obtain data.  If you really want the user to log out, in my opinion, the ONLY way is to blacklist the JWT.  If you receive the blacklisted token, you simply return 401.